# Meteor autoform hidden inputs based on select-radio

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

I am trying to link hidden inputs based on radio button selected and am stuck on how I would go about doing it. The autoform select-radio option helper creates an array with an internal id that makes it difficult to attach another helper and the values and names are not unique enough as well.

I was thinking of maybe adding the objects via an array of values into the radio button value then doing some processing in the before hook, but uhhhhh, I dont know really how to do that. I'd prefer that not to have additional input fields in the template if possible.

Template.example.html

```
{{#autoForm collection="arrayscollecti" id="insert-form" doc=currentDoc type="insert"}}
            {{> afFieldInput name="arrays"  options=radioHelper type="select-radio"}}
{{/autoform}}
```

Template.example.helper

```
radioHelper: function() {
 var array0 = this.object[0].objectA.objectA.value;
 var array1 = this.object[1].objectA.objectA.value;
 var hidden0 = this.object[0].objectA.objectB.differentvalue;
 var hidden1 = this.object[1].objectA.objectB.differentvalue;
 return [
    {label: array0, value: array0},
    {label: array1, value: array1}
   ];
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured it out. there was no answer to the question anywhere because its really specific to this scenario, but I hope the keywords in the title help others to find out how to post multiple hidden fields into autoform and pass simple schema. If anyone else has solution for this please post an answer.

the helper does not take anything but strings as values so I stringified it

```
radioHelper: function() {
var array0 = this.object[0].objectA.objectA.value;
var array1 = this.object[1].objectA.objectA.value;
var hidden0 = this.object[0].objectA.objectB.differentvalue;
var hidden1 = this.object[1].objectA.objectB.differentvalue;
var objectArray0 = JSON.stringify({"simpleschema1": this.object[0].objectA.objectA.value, "simpleschema2": "VARorNUMorSTRINGorOBJECT"}
var objectArray1 = JSON.stringify({"simpleschema1": this.object[1].objectA.objectA.value, "simpleschema2": VARorNUMor"STRING"orOBJECT}
return [
    {label: array0, value: objectArray0},
    {label: array1, value: objeactArray1}
   ];
},
```

Once you got that done then you need to create a before hook which will run through schema and hopefully pass. If it doesnt then you need to look at your helper or look at console.logs to see if the info is correct. I left in my createdat and createdby fields in case someone wants to add those before to the database without exposing in the HTML.

```
 AutoForm.hooks({
 'insert-form': {

before: {
  insert: function(doc, template) {
    var result = JSON.parse(doc.arrays);
    doc = result;
    doc.createdat = JSON.stringify(moment()._d);
    doc.ownerid = Meteor.userId();
    return doc;
  }
 }       
});
```